# Restore a mongo db from a directory

Tags: mongodb

I have all my collection in the following route /Download/database_backup
I trying to restore the database using the following command:

```
mongorestore -db database_bame /Download/database_backup
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
Wed Jan 22 15:46:49.119 ERROR: don't know what to do with file [/Download/database_backup]
```

What I'm doing wrong, I did the restore last week from the same directory and everything works great.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is `/Download/database_backup` a directory? What are its contents? Do a `ls /Download/database_backup` and paste here the output.

Comment: I have all my collections with the bson and json file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are giving the wrong path. Try this, but be sure the *path is correct*:

```
mongorestore --db <database_name> /Download/database_backup/
```

Comment: Can you respond in my comment on your question?

Comment: @Jean are you sure there is a file with a `.bson` extension inside there? If not, please add the extension `.bson` to it and retry.

Comment: Sure, I have 39 bson files and 39 metadata.json files (I have 39 collections on my database)

Comment: @Jean can you provide a structure of your `database_backup/` folder? Also, you are trying to backup all the databases or a specific one?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45813/discussion-between-agis-and-jean)

Comment: all the files are on the /Download/blabloo_pre folder and I trying to restore on my blabloo_development database